# org.Hs.eg.db output has more lines than the input- I need to combine the input and output

Tags: r, cbind

I'd like to combine data2 and the output from `org.Hs.eg.db`. But I realized `org.Hs.eg.db` added 3 extra lines. Do you have any suggestions to fix it?

```
head(data2)

   genes shp400_FC     T58A_FC      omo_FC
1   AVIL  2.730086 -1.10721312 -1.21584380
2   BAI2  3.104302 -2.17959085  0.16769160
3    CA9 -3.208643  0.03214854 -1.05244810
5   CNN3  2.121578 -0.36076018  0.53284659
6  CPNE6  4.477493 -0.39318830 -1.10612350
7 DNAH17  4.196555 -0.43432671  0.02131942

genes2 <- as.character(data2$genes)

entrez <- select(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = genes2, columns=c("ENTREZID"), 
                 keytype="SYMBOL")

head(entrez)

  SYMBOL ENTREZID
1   AVIL    10677
2   BAI2     <NA>
3    CA9      768
4   CNN3     1266
5  CPNE6     9362
6 DNAH17     8632

data2 <- cbind(data2, entrez)

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 13128, 13131
```

Comment: At the very least you should tag this `Bioconductor`. Also, there is a dedicated [Bioconductor help site](https://support.bioconductor.org/).

Comment: `mapIds()` provides strategies for dealing with 1:many maps.